# How to delete pending jobs on IBM Quantum Computer to retrieve units?

Tags: ibm-q-experience, qiskit

I am trying to run some code using `qiskit`, but I get the error message, that I have run out of necessary `Experiment Units`. I tried to remove pending jobs using the API with the following code

```
for job in api.get_jobs():
    if job["status"] == "RUNNING":
    api.cancel_job(id_job=job["id"], hub=None, group=None, project=None,
        access_token=None, user_id=None)
```

but it didn't work.

Am I even going in the right direction or is there some other way to retrieve these used `Experiment Units`? I have read, that they normally are given back just after the execution of program is finished or after 24 hours (depending on which one ends earlier), but I am waiting now for over than two days and nothing happens.

Comment: Does your program actually cancel the job, or does it fail to do that also

Comment: Also, I crossposted to the QISKit Slack to see if they might have an answer.

Comment: My program failed to cancel pending jobs. I am wondering, that naybe IBM has some difficulties, which will be resolved in the next week.

Comment: Your code looks like it doesn’t use the methods of QISKit 0.5.0. So maybe if you do it with the new version, it might work (and maybe not).

Comment: Can you specify, what should I change? 
Also, I think that there are some problems with their network, because nobody is running experiments (at least the interactive map on their page shows that).

Comment: You could try using the new basejob class. https://qiskit.org/documentation/_autodoc/qiskit.backends.BaseJob.html?highlight=job But you are right that an update is coming, so there is always hope that it’ll fix all our woes ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cancel Job is only available for the IBM Q Network, not for IBM Q Experience: https://github.com/QISKit/qiskit-api-py/blob/master/IBMQuantumExperience/IBMQuantumExperience.py#L795

In the next weeks, we hope that it is available for IBM Q Experience too.

Regarding to the credits... we are analyzing the problem. We have refilled your credits.

If you have any other issue, please post in qiskit (https://qiskit.org/) slack public channel :).